# dotnetopenauth and google login without redirection

Tags: c#, wpf, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to use dotnetopenauth to check if user have an account in gmail. If the password and username is corrent, I want my application to show the user some information. However all examples I found of dotnetopenauth require  redirection to gmail login page. Is there any way to just pass login and password parameters to some function and check if it is possible to login with this credentials?  I'm writing a desktop application that is why I don't want redirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings rsLoginInfo = new Google.GData.Client.RequestSettings("", txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: @NNovkovskiStevoBato Thanks for a answer. It lokks promising, however I would like to use dotnetOpenAuth. Is it possible with that library ?